# Can you identify these trees from the logs?

Tags: firewood, tree-identification

The trees that these logs came from were growing in Northeast Kansas.  Other than that, the pictures are really the only identifying information I have about them. I’m not sure whether any of them came from the same tree. Someone cut them down and I collected the wood. I would love to get an idea what kind of wood this is. (Even knowing if it’s deciduous vs evergreen would be nice.)

I’m thinking #5 is probably not identifiable since it lost its bark and all. But I had it laying with the others so it got to be in the picture. :)

Can anybody help identify these?

[image: Top View]

[image: Side View]

Answer (score 5):

#9 is a Plane tree (*[Platanus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platanus)*) species. Probably American Sycamore (*[Platanus occidentalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platanus_occidentalis)*)in the USA. [The bark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platanus#/media/File:Plane_Tree_bark_at_Tayac,_Dordogne.jpg) is characteristic of these trees.

I would guess that #'s 1, 2, 3 and possibly 4 all come from the same type of tree. I think probably hickory (*[Carya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hickory)*) species. They all have characteristic longitudinal deeply grooved bark. This won't be one of the shagbark hickory as these shed the bark in big peeling strips. It could be bitternut hickory, which has [similar bark](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Carya_cordiformis_(bark)#/media/File:Carya_cordiformis_(Bitternut_Hickory)_(33323804856).jpg), but I've only really seen the bark on the main trunk. Oak bark would be more split into plate-like structures than this.

#5 is a puzzle, very hard to tell without a close-up shot of the wood, particularly a clean-cut end.

#6 looks like it is a conifer species (there are quite a few genera), but which one is impossible to tell. My best bet would be *[Pinus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pine)*

#7 is a puzzle. It could be a dogwood, or possibly beech or even an upper branch from the plane tree. But there are a few other possibilities too.

#8 I have no idea.

Update: I think that #7 and #8 are probably the same thing, with #8 being a decayed/aged form and possibly both are also hickory from further out on the branches.

Note: I'm not from North America, but have spent a couple of years in TN, so YMMV on species.

Answer (score 0):

Not conifers , they are deciduous. Oak is very common, so that would be a first guess for 1,2,3 and 4. The others look a bit different. # 9 is something else like sycamore.

Comment: They could also be an [ornamental pear tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrus_calleryana); they look kind of similar to that bark for the ones you suggested Oak for